# How to prove that the projection length $\frac{x^T y}{\|x\|}$ is normally distributed if $x,y\sim N(0,I_p)$?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

$x,y\in\mathbb{R}^p$ are independently drawn from the standard multivariate Gaussian distribution $N(0,I_p)$. How do you prove that the projection length $z=\frac{x^T y}{\|x\|}$ is normally distributed?

If $x$ is fixed, then $z$ is just a linear combination of the entries of $y$, so it is normally distributed. And we can easily calculate the mean and variance, so $z|x\sim N(0,1)$ for any $x$. Is this enough to conclude that $z\sim N(0,1)$ unconditionally?

Comment: If you know that $z|x\sim N(0,1)$ you can use total law of probability to reach your desired conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

In essence yes! It follows from the law of total probability as mentioned by @Mathew Pilling. If you calculate $$P(z \le t) = \int P(z \le t|x) f_X(x)dx= \Phi(t)$$
since $P(z \le t|x) = \Phi(t)$, and $f_X$, the density of $x$ integrates to 1.